# sql INSERT condition as a select statement?

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, hive

I am trying to populate a table with HIVE sql. Both tables here have the same columns but I am only concerned with rows in tableSource that are not yet in tableDest.

The rows in the tables have an index field recordId (not primary). I want to add all rows from tableSource that have recordId GREATER than the highest recordId in tableDest.

I have a basic command structure with what I imagine has incorrect syntax?

```
INSERT INTO tableDest
SELECT * FROM tableSource
WHERE tableSource.recordId  >
 (SELECT MAX(recordId) FROM tableDest);
```

I just want the value from the last select statement to be used for the condition.

I have tried using variables to no success:

```
SET highest_record =SELECT MAX(recordId) FROM tableDest;
INSERT INTO tableDest
SELECT * FROM tableSource
WHERE tableSource.recordId  > ${hiveconf:highest_record};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`not exists` is the best option.

```
INSERT INTO tableDest
SELECT * 
FROM tableSource s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM tableDest d
                  WHERE s.recordId=d.recordId)
```

Comment: Thanks, saved me a lot of pain!